# Okular annotation settings: porting from Opensuse to Mint Mate

Tags: ubuntu, kde, opensuse, settings, okular

I have two laptops: one with OpenSuse 15 and another one with Mint.

I would like to have the same Okular settings (toolbar and annotations in particular) in both systems.

I have everything configured in OpenSuse and I'd like to bring those configurations to Mint. Do you know if there is a specific file that I should move to Mint? I haven't used Okular in Mint yet, but I'm sure I'll have to install KDE libraries.

I hope the whole KDE desktop environment is not needed..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `.config/okularrc` and `.config/okularpartrc` come to mind. But I don't know if that will suffice, I just checked my home dir. You'll probably need to check the contents of `rpm -ql okular-$YOUR_VERSION`, but this is just guessing, I've never tried what you're are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback,  Using that command I just see files in /usr/share/ /usr/lib64 /usr/bin

Comment: @eblock thank you, the files were those ones. Hope it helps other people too

Comment: Great! It would be nice if you would give that answer a vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.config/okularrc` and `.config/okularpartrc` come to mind. But I don't know if that will suffice, I just checked my home dir. You'll probably need to check the contents of `rpm -ql okular-$YOUR_VERSION`, but this is just guessing, I've never tried what you're are trying to achieve.